# Contour four variable plot matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, contour

I would like to plot four variables using Python Matplotlib. I am able to do this using the code below, which using artificial data. The code is from another question on stack.

Is there a way to generate a contour map within the 3D to better reflect the variation in the value of variable "c" as a function of the variables x,y, and z. I would like to make use of contours because the real data I have, the present type of graph has points which overlap a bit and the patterns in the data do not show up clearly.

It will work for my purposes if the contours are build with extrapolation between data points.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


def fourVariable_colorPlot():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

    x = np.random.standard_normal(100)
    y = np.random.standard_normal(100)
    z = np.random.standard_normal(100)
    c = np.random.standard_normal(100)

    ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=c, cmap=plt.hot())
    plt.show()


fourVariable_colorPlot()
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking for something that isn't shown here:

https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/contourf3d_demo2.html 
https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/contourf3d_demo.html
https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/contour3d_demo2.html

Comment: @Will, I am not able to work the data above into the three examples you suggest, though in principle I suppose one of these example type may work.